# Linux 64-abi, calling convention

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm reading [***intel manual***](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf) about calling convention and which register has which purpose. Here is what was specified in the `Figure 3.4: Register Usage`:

```
%rax       temporary register; with variable arguments
           passes information about the number of vector
           registers used; 1st return register
```

But in [linux api](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) we use `rax` to pass the function number. Is it consistent with what was specified in the intel manual? Actually I expected that (according to the manual) we will pass the function number into `rdi` (it is used for the 1st argument). And so forth...

Can I use `rax` to pass the first function argument in my hand-written functions? E.g.

```
mov rax, [array_lenght_ptr]
mov rdi, array_start_ptr
callq _array_sum
```

Comment: System calls use slightly different convention than user-space. Yes, you can do whatever you want in your hand written functions.

Comment: @Jester Doing whatever I want sounds a bit messy. I'd like to understand and adhere to the calling conventions.

Comment: @St.Antario The calling convention (SysV ABI, amd64 supplement) is documented [in this file](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf).  Read it carefully, everything is explained in there.

Comment: @fuz Seems the newer version of the manual I linked to

Comment: Notice the system call interface for 32bit and 64bit linux is very different. For 32bit, %ebx, %ecx, %edx; for 64bit %rdi, %rsi, %rdx. But the system call number is always passed by %eax(or %rax)

Comment: _"Doing whatever I want sounds a bit messy."_  **You** specifically asked whether you can ... I just answered.

Comment: @St.Antario Indeed!  Everything it says in there is correct. Note that §3.3 specifies a separate calling convention for system calls which includes the use of `rax` you already observed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That quote is talking about the *function*-calling convention, which is standardized by x86-64 System V ABI doc.

You're thinking of Linux's system-call calling convention, which is described in an appendix to the ABI doc, but that part isn't normative.  Anyway, the system call ABI puts the call number in `rax` because it's not an arg *to the system call*.  Alternatively, you can think of it like a 0th arg, the same way that variadic function calls pass the number of FP register-args in `al`.  (Fun fact: that makes it possible for the caller to pass even the first FP arg on the stack if they want to.)

But more importantly, **because call number in RAX makes a better ABI, and because of tradition: it's what the i386 system-call ABI does, too.**  And the i386 System V *function*-call ABI is totally different, using stack args exclusively.

This means system-call wrapper functions can just set `eax` and run `syscall` instead of needing to do something like

```
libc_write_wrapper_for_your_imagined_syscall_convention:
   ; copy all args to the next slot over
    mov r10, rdx   ; size_t count
    mov rdx, rsi   ; void *buf
    mov esi, edi   ; int fd
    mov edi, 1     ; SYS_write
    syscall
    cmp  rax, -4095
    jae  set_errno
    ret
```

instead of

```
actual_libc_write_wrapper:   ; glibc's actual code I think also checks for pthread cancellation points or something...
    mov eax, 1     ; SYS_write
    syscall
    cmp  rax, -4095
    jae  set_errno
    ret
```

Note the use of `r10` instead of `rcx` because `syscall` clobbers `rcx` and `r11` with the saved RIP and RFLAGS, so it doesn't have to write any memory with return information, and doesn't force user-space to put it somewhere the kernel can read it (like 32-bit `sysenter` does).

So the system-calling convention *couldn't* be the same as the function-calling convention.  (Or the function-calling convention would have had to choose different registers.)

For system calls with 4 or more args (or a generic wrapper that works for any system call) you do need a `mov r10, rcx`, but that's all.  (Unlike the 32-bit convention where a wrapper has to load args from the stack, and save/restore `ebx` because the kernel's poorly-chosen ABI uses it for the first arg.)

---

> Can I use rax to pass the first function argument in my hand-written functions?

Yes, do whatever you want for private helper functions that you don't need to call from C.

Choose arg registers to make things easier for the callers (or for the most important caller), or you'll be using any registers with fixed register choices (like `div`).

Note which registers are clobbered and which are preserved with a comment.  Only bother to save/restore registers that your caller actually needs saving / restoring, and choose which tmp regs you use to minimize push/pop.  Avoid a push/pop save/reload of registers that are part of a critical latency path in your caller, if your function is short.

Comment: Did not notice the appendix with kernel conventions before.